# Pubsubhubbub on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, websub

Previously Tumblr used to support Pubsubhubbub. They seemed to have stopped somewhere along the line, discovery of a hub on a feed URL is failing.

The [protocol](http://crackhoer.tumblr.com/rss) says there should be a *Link* header, but that's nowhere to be found.

Does anyone have a clue how to find a Pubsubhubbub hub for a Tumblr feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apparently](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/superfeedr/sxZpwDSVarY/D9w24ii45JgJ) Tumblr dropped Pubsubhubbub support so that's why it's not working anymore.

Comment: I would drop support for something I didn't like saying it.. that seems like a valid reason :P